# grails angularjs - modal not working as expected

Tags: grails, angularjs

I want to show modal(`encouragementModal`) only when user clicks on **Encourage** button.

### Configuration

GSP View `_encourage.gsp` is :

```
<div ng-controller="EncouragementController">
    <g:if test="${notEncouraged}">
                           <button class="btn" ng-click="openEncouragementModal()">Encourage</button>
                           <div modal="encouragementModal" close="closeEncouragementModal()" options="opts">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h3>Encourage!</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                    You are about to encourage with {{amount}}.
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                               <button class="btn btn-info cancel" ng-click="encourage()">Confirm</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-warning cancel" ng-click="close()">Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </g:if>
                    <g:else>
                          Thank you for encouraging.
                    </g:else>
```

The `EncouragementController.js` is

```
function EncouragementController($scope, $http) {
  /**
   * open payment dialog
   */
  $scope.openEncouragementModal = function (amount) {
        $scope.encouragementModal = true;
  };

  $scope.closeEncouragementModal = function () {
        $scope.closeMsg = 'You canceled the encouragement’;
        $scope.encouragementModal = false;
  };


  $scope.opts = {
        backdropFade: true,
        dialogFade:true
  };


}

EncouragementController.$inject = [ '$scope', '$http'];
```

### Question

Only the **Encourage** button should have been visible for the first time, but what I see is button along with the `encouragementModal` and it's buttons.

So, how do I do that?

### References I followed

[1] [Modal (ui.bootstrap.modal)](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

[2] [Simple Grails + AngularJS Example](http://compiledammit.com/2012/08/17/simple-grails-angularjs-example/)

Comment: Put it in a fiddle or plunkr. Much easier to help that way

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide it at first and only display it when scope.encouragementModal value is true.

```
<div modal="encouragementModal" ng-show="encouragementModal" options="opts">
```

Comment: Putting `ng-show="encouragementModal"` shows only the *Encourage* button but when clicked, the `encouragementModal` appears right below the button embedded in the browser instead of appearing as a panel.

Comment: If you set the ng-show on the actual modal div, when you click the button, the scope.encouragementModal is set to true and the ng-show will evaluate to true showing the modal.